# How should I prepare a log home for vinyl siding?

Tags: vapor-barrier

I am going to side over a log home.  Some of the logs are deteriorated and the maintenance has not been done for years but for the most part the logs are solid.
I want to fur out the logs with 1 x 4 pine furring strips and attach the CertainTeed CedarBoard insulated siding over the furring strips.  There would be a air gap in-between the furring strips and at the bottom of the wall.

Does anyone have experience with this type of project or can anyone give proper installation over the logs?  The logs are to uneven to sheet over directly so it is going to have to be furred out.

Should I install a vapor barrier over the logs or allow the logs to breath as described above?

Any help greatly appreciated.  Just trying to keep from having to remove the logs if possible.

Comment: You should consider adding a picture of your home's exterior for clarity.

Comment: Just a comment but I would think you would be reducing the value of the home, repairing and re staining logs probably will not cost any more than siding. But it is a good question, I would probably use a house wrap and possibly foam board insulation for some additional insulation. +

Answer (score 1):

Your first question is a bit unclear, but I'd consider installing blocking to bring the wall on plane, then OSB or plywood sheathing. You could have a selection of spacer blocks on hand and pull lines to check the needed thickness at each vertical on 24" centers. I'd probably pull horizontal lines top and bottom, then pull between them as you install the blocks.

Installing just furring strips will leave you with a wavy wall unless you also do the varying-thickness blocking. Sheathing would cost roughly the same anyway and give your siding better support.

You should have housewrap (a drain plane) behind the siding. This is not a vapor barrier and *will* allow the wall to breathe. Almost no one installs poly sheeting, for example, behind siding.